# Symfony construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, none given

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony-2.8

I can't understand this error. I tried all things but can't solve this. Can someone tell me where is my fault please .

The error :

> FatalThrowableError in MemcachedCacheProvider.php line 14: Type error:
>   Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Data\CacheProvider\MemcachedCacheProvider::__construct()
>   must implement interface
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, none given,
>   called in ...app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 373

MemcachedCacheProvider.php ;

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Data\CacheProvider;

    use AppBundle\Data\Interfaces\ICacheProvider;
    use AppBundle\Data\Interfaces\ICacheItem;
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

    class MemcachedCacheProvider implements ICacheProvider
    {
        /** @var ContainerInterface */
        protected $_container;

        public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
            $this->_container = $container;
        }
public function GetItem($cacheKey)
    {
        $result = $this->_container->get('beryllium_cache.client')->get($cacheKey);
        if($result === null
            || !$result)
            return null;

        return $result;
    }

    public function GetItems(array $cacheKeys)
    {
        $cachedItems = array();
        $cache = $this->_container->get('beryllium_cache.client');

        foreach($cacheKeys as $key) {
            $item = $cache->get($key);

            if($item === null || !$item)
                return null;

            $cachedItems[] = $item;
        }

        if(count($cachedItems) == 0)
            return null;

        return $cachedItems;
    }

    public function RemoveItem($cacheKey)
    {
        $this->_container->get('beryllium_cache.client')->delete($cacheKey);
    }

    public function RemovePrefix($namespaceKey)
    {
        //Used namespaces for memcache, so incrementing namespace value will now work as removing prefix
        $this->_container->get('beryllium_cache.client')->increment($namespaceKey);

        //TODO: No solution for removing items by prefix in memcached. Flushing cache!
        //$this->_container->get('beryllium_cache.client')->flush();
    }

    public function SetItem(ICacheItem $cacheItem)
    {
        if($cacheItem->GetItem() === null)
            return;

        $this->_container->get('beryllium_cache.client')->set($cacheItem->GetKey(), $cacheItem, ($cacheItem->GetExpireTimeStamp() == 0 ? 0 : ($cacheItem->GetExpireTimeStamp()-time())));
    }

    public function SetItems(array $items, $expireTimeStamp)
    {
        $cache = $this->_container->get('beryllium_cache.client');

        foreach($items as &$item) {
            $cache->set($item->GetKey(), $item, ($expireTimeStamp == 0 ? 0 : ($expireTimeStamp-time())));
        }
    }

    public function GetNamespace($namespaceKey)
    {
        $ns = $this->GetItem($namespaceKey);

        if(empty($ns)) {
            //generate a random value to use as namespace and store it
            $ns = mt_rand();

            $this->_container->get('beryllium_cache.client')->set($namespaceKey, $ns, 0);
        }

        return $ns;
    }
```

And the services.yml ;

```
ayon_app.cacheprovider:
        class: AppBundle\Data\CacheProvider\MemcachedCacheProvider
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

Comment: Where is that service used/injected? You don't, by chance, create it somewhere *by hand*?

Comment: This service using in AppBundle and the services.yml in same bundle. But the constructor give me that error. I can't see my fault.

Comment: Please add the exact code where you access or inject the service.

Comment: @Yoshi If I don't understand you please correct me. That is exact code just I think you don't need my all codes cause that problem. My problem about dependecy injection and just sent related codes.

Comment: As it stands, the provider and the service definition is correct. But the service is not created properly. So the problem probably lies where you inject/use the service. For example, in a controller you might use `$this->get(...)`, but if by any chance you do `$x = new MemcachedCacheProvider(...)` then that would be a problem. So I don't need *all* your code, just the context where it is used/created/injected.

Comment: Ok I see. I editted the source.

Comment: Sorry, that's not the code I asked about. The code of the `MemcachedCacheProvider` is really not relevant. What needs to be inspected is **where** the service is used.

Comment: @Yoshi I used it in services_dev.yml for caching. So I dont call it anotherwhere. After fix this I will use it just like this $cacheItem =  new CacheItem($cacheKey, $results, 0); But right now I can't use it any where

Comment: Ok, I think you don't understand what I mean, probably due to english not being my first language. Please check in your code or configuration where you can find the string `'ayon_app.cacheprovider'`.

Comment: No I can understand but this is a caching provider. I use this service in services.yml as a service but I cant call it right now because the injection problem. If I fix this I will call it as I said. So I the problem is block me. You asked me where I call this funtion For example in a repository in services.yml and arguments section with this line cacheProvider: "@ayon_app.cacheprovider"

Comment: So at no place in your code you have something like `new MemcachedCacheProvider(...)`, only ever `@ayon_app.cacheprovider`? And this mainly in other configuration files? If so, have you tried clearing the cache? Simply delete `app/cache/dev` and `app/cache/prod`.

Comment: Yes I tried but gave me same error. If I delete the __construct Works well but cant use "get" function. I cant see any error.

Comment: Ok, without full access to your code, I guess I can't help you from here. The problem is pretty clear (the service does not get constructed with all required arguments), but without digging around, I can't tell you where to look.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it is extremely bad practice to inject the complete Container into a service, this because you will also get all the services you did not ask for / need. So instead of type-hinting `ContainerInterface`, type-hint only the services you actively use inside of the code and update the service definition appropriately.

Furthermore, when using this cache provider in other classes. You will have to type-hint `MemcachedCacheProvider` instead of using the `new` keyword to create a new instance of it.

Tip: When you are not sure about any type-hinted service names within the service.yml, you can simply set the following parameter within your service to automagically resolve them: `autowire: true`